# SQL Query taking long to execute especially with offset and fetch for pagination

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2014

This is the query I'm running for a report. It takes about 20 seconds to run without the `offset` and `fetch`. With those two, The query doesn't even complete in 10 minutes.

```
select *
-- h.ActionDate as Date, h.Action, h.Actor , h.PaymentLotNo 
-- , sh.OwnerName as OwnersName,sh.TECHID as TechId, sh.Id as SubsidyCardId, sh.TotalSubsidy as SubsidyAmount
-- ,a.ToleEng + '-' + v.NameEng + cast(a.Ward as nvarchar(4)) + ',' + d.NameEng + ',' + s.StateNameEng as Address
from common.CTB_SUBSIDY_APPLICATION_HISTORY h 
join fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER sh on sh.LotNumber = h.PaymentLotNo 
join fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_ADDRESS sa on sa.SubsidyId = sh.Id 
join common.CTB_ADDRESS a on a.AddressID = sa.AddressId 
join COMMON.CLK_STATE s on s.StateId = a.StateID 
join COMMON.CLK_DISTRICTS d on d.DistrictCd = a.DistrictCD 
join common.CLK_DISTRICT_VDC v on v.VdcCd = a.VdcCd where 1 = 1 order by h.ActionDate desc
offset 790 rows 
FETCH first 10 row only
```

The following is [the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1ib8d8qI) for the query.

[image: Execution Plan]

How do I optimize this query?

Comment: If it only takes 20 seconds without the offset/fetch, can you fetch the whole data set and paginate in the application? If not, can you post up the table schemas and indexes, and maybe post the execution plan on [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: Just curious. If it takes 20 seconds to return everything, how quick is it, if you use row_number without offset/fetch?

Comment: @HandyD, There are 897 rows for now, which will drastically increase in the actual use scenario. This is the execution plan. https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=H1ib8d8qI

Comment: could you please add the plan without offset-fetch? do these joins eliminate any rows or you have foreign keys/corresponding rows in all tables? do you really need to select * or you just need particular columns?

Comment: I would start with an index on `fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER(PaymentLotNo)` and specify the explict column list for tuning purposes since `SELECT *` limits the plan choices.

Answer (score 2):

Using `OFFSET...FETCH` likely introduces a row goal (in the same way that `TOP` does so - see [Setting and Identifying Row Goals in Execution Plans](https://sqlperformance.com/2018/02/sql-plan/setting-and-identifying-row-goals) by Paul White for more information on that subject).  This is why you see such a difference without that part of the query - the lack of a row goal changes the plan entirely.

The row goal leads to SQL Server choosing the series of nested loops joins in the execution plan you shared.  This would normally be fine, but my guess it that the joins are more restrictive than the estimates indicate, and thus it takes a lot longer than expected to get the 10 rows requested.

You can test this theory by adding `OPTION (QUERYTRACEON 4138)` to the end of the query and running it again.

---

As far as a proper solution - as Dan Guzman suggested, you could try creating a narrow index on `fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER`:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_PaymentLotNo
ON FSAMS.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER (PaymentLotNo)
INCLUDE (OwnerName, TECHID, Id, TotalSubsidy)
```

Also, don't use `SELECT *` for your performance-related testing, as it's definitely going to change the final plan that you get (as compared with the column list of the actual query).

There is an implicit conversion going on that could be throwing the query's estimates off - `LotNumber` is stored as a string in the `CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER` table, which is being converted to an `int` before being joined to `PaymentLotNo` in `CTB_SUBSIDY_APPLICATION_HISTORY`.  You should `ALTER` these columns to have matching data types if possible.

---

Side note: you're running SQL Server 2014 RTM, which is out of support.  You should upgrade to the latest service pack.  Also, consider enabling TF 4199 at that time, as the issue you're experiencing *could* be related to an optimizer bug that has since been corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Like Dan Guzman said, you should add an index on fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER(LotNumber). The clustered index scan of this table represents 59% of the cost of the query.

[image: Clustered scan]

It seems also that sh.LogNumber and h.PaymentLotNo are not the same type. It gives you an implicit conversion warning in your plan on sh.LotNumber, you should try to fix that.

[image: implicit conversion]

And you should paste a new plan without the SELECT *

And execute the query, so we not only get estimated plan, but the real execution plan. That way we can also see if the estimated and actual row count match and see if statistics are out of date.

Answer (score 0):

first of all in your query `where 1=1` is nor clear .

Apart from all suggesation there is still one major scope of improving the given query.

Apply `Paging` in only main query.
Main query which affect the number of rows in Paging.

Sorry if I am not clear about Main query, let me explain with example.

```
;With CTE as
    (
    select 
  h.ActionDate as Date, h.Action, h.Actor , h.PaymentLotNo 
  , sh.OwnerName as OwnersName
  ,sh.TECHID as TechId
  , sh.Id as SubsidyCardId
  , sh.TotalSubsidy as SubsidyAmount
  ,a.ToleEng + '-' + v.NameEng + cast(a.Ward as nvarchar(4)) + ',' + d.NameEng + ',' + s.StateNameEng as Address
 from fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_HEADER sh 
 join common.CTB_SUBSIDY_APPLICATION_HISTORY h on sh.LotNumber = h.PaymentLotNo 
 join fsams.CTB_SUBSIDY_CARD_ADDRESS sa on sa.SubsidyId = sh.Id 

 where 1 = 1 order by h.ActionDate desc
 offset 790 rows 
    FETCH first 10 row only
    )

select 
 sa.*
 from CTE sa 
 join common.CTB_ADDRESS a on a.AddressID = sa.AddressId
 join COMMON.CLK_STATE s on s.StateId = a.StateID 
 join COMMON.CLK_DISTRICTS d on d.DistrictCd = a.DistrictCD 
 join common.CLK_DISTRICT_VDC v on v.VdcCd = a.VdcCd
```

Always Join `Master` table in final resultset.

If it is clear to you and if it is possible then you can remove few more table from Join inside `CTE` and put them in final query.

Put the result of CTE in `Temp` table.